# Getting variables from a custom Layout in Android?

Tags: android

In android, I have a custom layout I built:

```
public class ButtonMatch extends RelativeLayout
{
    private final TextView text_round, text_match, text_player1, text_player2;

    public ButtonMatch(final Context context) {
        super(context);
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.button_match, this, true);

        text_round = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_round);
        text_match = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_match);
        text_player1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_player1);
        text_player2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_player2);
    }

    public void setRound(String text) {
        text_round.setText(text);
    }

    public void setMatch(String text) {
        text_match.setText(text);
    }

    public void setPlayer1(String text) {
        text_player1.setText(text);
    }

    public void setPlayer2(String text) {
        text_player2.setText(text);
    }

    public String getPlayer1() {
        return text_player1.getText();
    }

    public String getPlayer2() {
        return text_player2.getText();
    }
}
```

Then I am adding this layout in code with the following:

```
ButtonMatch button = new ButtonMatch(this);

button.setLayoutParams(layout);
button.setTag(match.get("id"));
button.setMatch(match.get("identifier").toString());
button.setPlayer1(players.get(match.get("player1_id").toString()));
button.setPlayer2(players.get(match.get("player2_id").toString()));
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ChallongeMatch.class);
        intent.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_API_KEY, API_KEY);
        intent.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_SUBDOMAIN, SUBDOMAIN);
        intent.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_EVENT_ID, EVENT_ID);
        intent.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MATCH_ID, view.getTag().toString());
        intent.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_PLAYER1, view.getPlayer1());
        intent.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_PLAYER2, view.getPlayer2());
    }
});
```

What I am missing though, is in the Intent with the onClickListener, I am trying to get the contents of the `text_player1` and `text_player2` as follows:

```
        intent.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_PLAYER1, view.getPlayer1());
        intent.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_PLAYER2, view.getPlayer2());
```

The problem is those two functions don't work `getPlayer1()` and `getPlayer2`, because they dont exist in the view...

How do I get these two functions to work. I don't know a lot about Android/Java yet, so please be explain as much as you can.

Comment: What is `view` in `view.getPlayer1()`? And if you know its your layout, why don't you cast it?

Comment: Huh? I dont know what you mean...

Comment: Please explain "because they dont exist in the view..."

Comment: Its from the onClickListener

Comment: You set the click listener on your View, so you could just cast it. Try `(ButtonMatch) view.getPlayer1()`

Comment: ButtonMatch is not a view... its a relativelayout...

Comment: Please have a look at the [class hierarchy at the top](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html). Everything in android that you put on the screen is a `View`. It is the base class

Comment: Casting it like that doesn't work either way... `cannot find symbol method getPlayer1()`

Comment: I'm sorry. `((ButtonMatch) view).getPlayer1()`

Comment: That worked... can you make this an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot casting `view` to `ButtonMatch`.

This is safe, because you set the click listener on the button object.

Change your code to

```
((ButtonMatch) view).getPlayer1()
```

to access the method on your object.